# having trouble with html checkbox

Tags: php, javascript, html

I can't figure out why my checkbox is always evaluating to "yes" regardless of what is checked.

the html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="email" id="email" value="yes">Yes<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="email" id="email" value="no" checked >No<br>
```

which is being accessed by

```
var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
```

and the php is just `$_GET`-ing the value of 'email' but it always processes it as it being set to "yes".

Comment: You should have a **unique** id for every html element. Thus, since you have two id="email", this is not good.

Comment: Note also that the value of unchecked checkboxes doesn't get submitted so if neither box is checked you won't get "yes" _or_ "no" in your PHP. Though I don't think it makes sense for a yes/no option to allow neither to be selected, so why aren't you using radio buttons for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because ID attribute should be unique, and `document.getElementById` returns first matched element.

Comment: I just have a question; I added if(document.getElementById('email').checked == true)
 {
  var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
 }                                                               to check the checkboxes, but it has slowed down processing by a lot, and I'm curious why.

Comment: I doubt that only this slowed down your processing, maybe there are some parts that executes because variable `email` was set? By the way your approach to dealing with checkboxes will be highly ineffective for more than 2 choices, instead of assigning id to them, assign ID to form element and iterate through it's elements using inputs `name` to check which one is checked.

Answer (score 1):

Its true that you should be using radio buttons if you only want a yes/no answer, have you used checkboxes intentionally? The radio button code would look like this as you wrote for the checkboxes:

**PHP:**

```
<?PHP
$selected_radio = $_POST['answer'];
print $selected_radio;
?>
```

**HTML:**

```
<FORM name ="form1" method ="post" action ="radioButton.php">
 <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='answer' value= 'Yes'>Yes
 <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='answer' value= 'No'>No
 <Input type = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" VALUE = "Select a Radio Button">
</FORM>
```

If you really want to use checkboxes, then give them separate ID's and check them individually:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="email" id="email_yes" value="yes">Yes<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="email" id="email_no" value="no" checked >No<br>
```

**JS:**

```
var email = (document.getElementById('email_yes').value == 1) 'yes' : 'no';
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply put, because it's a checkbox. A radio button (`type="radio"`) is the type which enforces only one of the boxes in a group can be checked, and is probably what you want.